# PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_country"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, npgsql

I am using EF Core 2.0 and Postgres 9.6. Whenever I insert data I get the error

> PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "PK_country"

By tracing it looks like EF doesnt generate AutoIncrement column

My Model

```
public partial class Country
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Country Name")]
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(country);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
```

Exception

> ```
> > PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique
> > constraint "PK_country"
> > 
> >     Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<DoReadMessage>d__148.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<ReadMessage>d__147.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<ReadMessage>d__147.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader+<NextResult>d__32.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)
> >     Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader+<<NextResultAsync>b__31_0>d.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)
> >     Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand+<Execute>d__71.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand+<ExecuteDbDataReader>d__92.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand+<>c__DisplayClass90_0+<<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand+<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> >     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch+<ExecuteAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
> ```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please update the post and tags. ASP.NET CORE2 is irrelevant, EF **Core**, version and used Postgres provider are.

Comment: Ok I udated the post

Comment: Thanks. See [Serial (Autoincrement) Columns](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html#serial-autoincrement-columns) and if the issue described in [Upgrading from 1.0.x](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/migration/1.1.html#upgrading-from-10x) applies to your scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I found the solution**. The issue was I was seed the database with the script from the sql file.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(baseDir + "\\data.sql"));
```

The insert contains

```
ALTER TABLE country DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
INSERT INTO country .......
```

So the sequence current value was not updating. Current value remained 1.So when I inserted with application. Autoincrment become 1 hence **PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_country"**.

**Resolution**

After **ALTER TABLE country ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;** add **SELECT pg_catalog.setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('country', 'country_id'), MAX(country_id)) FROM country;**

Now it application run successifully.

Hope help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the solution here was already found, the question does not specify that you load the data from some `.sql` file. If you had been loading the data in the following way, this would have also generated the same error:

```
_context.Add(new Country { CountryId = 0, CountryName = "MyCountry" });
_context.Add(new Country { CountryId = 1, CountryName = "MyCountry" });
```

The reason is, that (I don't know why) the first row will have `CountryId = 1` and the second one also `CountryId = 1`. Which leads to duplicate key value.

This happens with:

- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.1.2
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2.3

Comment: I have the same issue, I set the IDs when seeding, my version PostgreSQL 3.1.0, I update the package now to 3.1.3 and It fixed on this version wtihout changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue after seeding data for my tests and then trying to insert a new entity.

The [solution](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/pull/1317) that fixes this issue states:

> When inserting explicit IDs (during seeding), PostgreSQL doesn't
> update the sequence value for auto-generated columns; this results in
> unique constraint violations when the user next attempts to insert a
> new entity.

A possible solution in your case would be to add the below snippet to your DBContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    => modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(c => c.CountryId)
        .HasIdentityOptions(startValue: 100);
```

You will then just need to ensure that any seed ids are set below the startValue.
More details can be found on the [npgsql documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/generated-properties.html?tabs=13%2Cefcore5#identity-sequence-options)